# What's happening with CWnd icon

Tags: windows, icons

I have a CWnd window which I create dynamically, and it seems that the icon for title bar area and task bar is picked at random or something.

To set the icon, I call:

```
// Set the icon for this dialog.  The framework does this automatically when the application's main window is not a dialog
m_hIcon = AfxGetApp()->LoadIconW(IDI_ICON);
SetIcon(m_hIcon, TRUE);         // Set big icon
SetIcon(m_hIcon, FALSE);        // Set small icon
```

As in MFC samples, but it seems that the 32x32 icon is always chosen and downscaled, even though there are other, closer matches available. The icon in the title bar is actually only 16x16, but it gets created from 32x32 version.

This causes a mess when 32x32 icon is more detailed than the 16x16 one, as the downscaled icon looks like a blur.

CFrameWnd windows seem to behave differently somehow, as they seem to choose closer match.

Does anyone know a solution to force feed smaller icon in title bar so that I could keep the larger icons for W7 task tray?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is LoadIcon, not LoadIconW, this compiles by accident.  The MFC method uses the LoadIcon() API function.  From the SDK documentation:

> LoadIcon can only load an icon whose
>   size conforms to the SM_CXICON and
>   SM_CYICON system metric values. Use
>   the LoadImage function to load icons
>   of other sizes.

Use LoadImage() instead so you can pass an appropriate size.  Make *two* calls to retrieve a large and a small version.  Or store the small icon image in another icon with another resource ID.

Comment: +1 If you're more of a "give me the codez" type, check out [this article](http://www.borngeek.com/code/system-menu-icon-bug/). Although, instead of hard-coding "16" as it suggests, I recommend calling `GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSMICON)` to determine the *correct* size.

Comment: But what about those 256x256 PNG compressed images or 64x64 icons, doesn't the 7 use them in some other cases than in C(XY)ICON? For exe it seems it takes the first icon from resources, but the icons are used in so many places that it seems 64x64 icon could appear anywhere (Alt tab, small/big task tray, notification area), and if I'll load the CXICONxCYICON icon as the large icon and CXSMICONxCSMYICON as the small icon won't it break in some other cases?

Comment: Also, it seems that if system returns C(XY)ICON as, say, 25x25, but I have 16x16, 32x32, 64x64 and 256x256 icons, then the LoadImage will load the 64x64 icon?

Comment: It is quite unusual to have the desktop running with a system icon size that's not a multiple of 16.  No idea really.  But seeing it pick an icon that gives it the best odds doesn't surprise me.  Ask at superuser.com